# Paragon-NTFS only let me save files into NTFS Drive from Finder Application

Tags: macos, error, ntfs

I just upgraded my Mac OS into Lion. I use Paragon NTFS to apply ntfs write mode. While working using Microsoft office, i noticed that i couldn't save any file from outlook, word, excel into NTFS drive from my external drive.

From outlook, there is no error messages, but from word i got this pop up error:

> Word Cannot save or create this file. the disk may full or write-protected
>
> Try one or more following:
>
> - Free more memory
> - Make sure that the disk you want to save is not full, write-protected, or damaged.

Did anyone ever experiencing this kind error? Don't know yet whether Microsoft Office bugs or not, but i could write any file from finder to this ntfs drive.

thanks.

update1: after i check with other application, it still failed to save any file into my ntfs drive. looks like the problem comes from Paragon. anyway i changed the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Tuxera NTFS](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/), it solves the problem!

Comment: Actually i prefer to use paragon-ntfs regarding the performance issue. But, if i want to apply tuxera whether i need to remove paragon-ntfs first?

Comment: anyway just tried your suggestion, by firstly remove the Paragon, then install the tuxera for ntfs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That error is not related to MS Office. It is a filesystem error related to writing to the NTFS disk. I'm guessing that the version of Paragon NTFS you have isn't compatible with Lion. Looking at [Paragon's forum](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/forumdisplay.php?f=111) for Paragon they have v9.0 which should work better.

You can also check out the [OSXFUSE project](https://github.com/osxfuse) which provides similar support for writing to NTFS.

Comment: Hi Nate, i think you are right. there is something wrong with paragon here. I tried to use another application to save file into my external drive still failed. The things that makes me confused on my problem here is why paragon ntfs only allow me to write any ntfs drive with finder. FYI, i use paragon v9.0.1(the latest).